# Xamarin form preview shows only Mockview

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am using Xamarin Forms on Visual Studio 2019. In every XAML forms of my project, when I try to show the preview I get only an orange box with the text "Mockview". I don't get any error message. My application build and works corretly but I can't see the preview.

This is the screenshot:
[image]

My exact versions are:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.2.3
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.03752
- Xamarin   16.2.0.95
- Xamarin Designer   16.2.0.375
- Xamarin Templates   16.3.117
- Xamarin.Android SDK   9.4.1.0

Any suggestion?

UPDATE:
The problem appears in release mode. In debug mode, after full reboot, it works, but sometimes not. 
Sometimes appears an error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.set_PreferredTheme(Theme value) in E:\A\_work\89\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\DesignerProject.cs:line 858
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidDesignerSession.SetTheme(Theme theme, Boolean triggerChange) in E:\A\_work\89\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\AndroidDesignerSession.cs:line 370
   at Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview.AndroidXamlRenderer.<RenderOneXaml>d__23.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\89\s\Xamarin.Designer.Forms\Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview\Android\AndroidXamlRenderer.cs:line 151
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview.AndroidXamlRenderer.<RenderXamls>d__24.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\89\s\Xamarin.Designer.Forms\Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview\Android\AndroidXamlRenderer.cs:line 286
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

Sometimes appears the error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's based on your design, when you design perfectly, it will work but anyone attribute will not valid or wrong, it doesn't shown but the output comes perfectly. because not valid attributes are ignored.

I recommend to use HotXaml or Live [Reload](https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/HotReload)